# Regex pattern to get number between forward slashes at the end of a URL

Tags: regex

I have a string URL that I just want to grab the number at the very end between "pokemon/" and "/".

"http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"

so far I have this -

```
var regexPat = /\/d+\//
"http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/".match(regexPat)[0].slice(1,2) // returns 1
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Efficient? In what sense?

Comment: perhaps just a cleaner way of doing with just regex? is there a way to extract the number with one regex pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may capture the value with a `/\/pokemon\/(\d+)\//` regex:

```js
var s = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/";
var m = s.match(/\/pokemon\/(\d+)\//);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
// or 
console.log( 
  (res="http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/".match(/\/pokemon\/(\d+)\//)) ? res[1] : ""
);
```

**Details**:

- `\/pokemon\/` - a literal text `/pokemon/`
- `(\d+)` - Capture group 1 matching 1 or more digits
- `\/` - a `/` symbol.

Comment: is the () used to capture? what is the term used for the parenthesis so I can learn more about how to capture the regex in between certain patterns?

Comment: `(...)` is called a [**capturing group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).  Also, see [*Grouping and back references* at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). If you plan to match multiple values, and access captures, you need to use `/g` global modifier with the regex, and use it in `RegExp#exec` inside a loop to retrieve each match object. `String#match`, when used with a "global" regex, discards all captured values.